# Yii selenium functional testing issue

Tags: php, selenium, yii, phpunit

When I run my functional test

```
phpunit functional/LoginTest.php
```

It starts my page in browser

`$this->open('http://mysite.com/');`

But it uses `index.php` instead of `index-test.php` and I have no idea why.

In `WebTestCase` class there is a constant

`define('TEST_BASE_URL','http://mysite.com/index-test.php/');`

and the setUp method of WebTestCase

```
protected function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->setBrowser('*googlechrome');
        $this->setBrowserUrl(TEST_BASE_URL);
    }
```

Please, tell me why does it keep calling `index.php` instead of `index-test.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `$this->open('http://mysite.com/');` this **absolute url**.
If you use it, you must do so: `$this->open('http://mysite.com/index-test.php');`

If you use **relative URL**, you must do so: $this->open(''); - this open `TEST_BASE_URL`

And once again reread the http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/test.functional